# CakePHP4: Where should I put my custom PasswordHasher

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I implemented CakePHP4 authentication following this:

https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/tutorials-and-examples/cms/authentication.html

It worked, then I need to use my custom PasswordHasher to satisfy the client requirements.  I couldn't find any tutorial to do that, but figured out the following code works.

In `Application.php`:

```
public function getAuthenticationService(ServerRequestInterface $request): AuthenticationServiceInterface {

    // ....

    $authenticationService->loadIdentifier('Authentication.Password', [
        'fields' => [
            'username' => 'username',
            'password' => 'password',
        ],
        'passwordHasher' => [
            'className' => 'Authentication.MyCustom',
        ]
    ]);
```

The problem is that I need to put `MyCustomPasswordHasher.php` file in `vendor\cakephp\authentication\src\PasswordHasher` in order to make this work.  Of course I don't want to put my own code under vendor directory.

Temporarily, I created and used `src\Authentication\PasswordHasher` directory and forced to make it work by doing this:

```
    spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
        if (strpos($class, 'MyCustomPasswordHasher') !== false) {
            require_once __DIR__ . '/' . str_replace(['\\', 'App/'], [DS, ''], $class) . '.php';
        }
    });
```

Is there any cleaner way to accomplish the purpose in CakePHP4?  Where should I put custom codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use plugin notation for the [**short name**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/app.html#finding-classes), pass only `'MyCustom'`, then it will look inside of your application, in the `App\PasswordHasher` namespace, so your class would accordingly go into

```
src/PasswordHasher/MyCustomPasswordHasher.php
```

Alternatively you can always pass a fully qualified name, meaning you could put your class wherever you want, as long as the composer autoloader can resolve it:

```php
'passwordHasher' => [
    'className' => \Some\Custom\Namespaced\PasswordHasher::class,
]
```